# error: react-native-smart-splashscreen

Tags: splash-screen, react-native

react-native-smart-splash-screen/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecomponent/splashscreen/RCTSplashScreenPackage.java:23: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
1 error
:react-native-smart-splashscreen:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-smart-splashscreen:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

  > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 9.971 secs
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

MainApplication.java

```
import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.github.yamill.orientation.OrientationPackage;
import com.reactnativecomponent.splashscreen.RCTSplashScreenPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;



public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
            new OrientationPackage()
      );
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
              new MainReactPackage(),
              new RCTSplashScreenPackage()    //register Module
      );
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.reactnativecomponent.splashscreen.RCTSplashScreen;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "HeadThink";
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Intent intent = new Intent("onConfigurationChanged");
        intent.putExtra("newConfig", newConfig);
        this.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        RCTSplashScreen.openSplashScreen(this);   //open splashscreen
        //RCTSplashScreen.openSplashScreen(this, true, ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);   //open splashscreen fullscreen
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

RCTSplashScreenPackage

```
package com.reactnativecomponent.splashscreen;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class RCTSplashScreenPackage implements ReactPackage {

    @Override
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Arrays.<NativeModule>asList(
                new RCTSplashScreenModule(reactContext)
        );
    }

    @Override
    public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Arrays.<ViewManager>asList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what your question is, and what you've already done to try to fix it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the most common error arising after the update of RN 0.47.1 .
You can check the latest release [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases).

In the release it is stated **Remove unused createJSModules calls**.
Therefore in your RCTSplashScreenPackage remove or comment these lines:

```
@Override
public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() {
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

I hope this helps everyone.

Comment: Worked for me... Thank you!